# Closed form expression for the given map?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Say we have a map that sends an intger to a finite tuple as follows:

$3 \rightarrow (3,2,4,1,5,2,4,3)$

$4 \rightarrow (4,3,5,2,6,1,7,2,6,3,5,4)$

and in general:

$n \rightarrow (n,n-1,n+1,n-2,n+2,\cdots,1,2n-1,2,2n-2,\cdots,n-1,n+1,n)$

Is there a more compact way I could write this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_k$, $k=0,\ldots,4n-5$ be your tuple. This expression should do the job:

$$
a_k =
\begin{cases}
-\frac{\lvert k-2n+2 \rvert}{2} + 2n-1,  & \text{if $k$ is even} \\
\frac{\lvert k-2n+3 \rvert}{2} + 1,  & \text{if $k$ is odd} \\
\end{cases}
$$

Or, if you like a more convoluted form:

$$
a_k = (-1)^{k+1}\frac{\lvert k-2n+2+\frac{1-(-1)^k}{2}\rvert}{2}+2n-1-(1-(-1)^k)(n-1) $$

I checked the cases $n=3$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B%28-1%29%5E%28k%2B1%29*abs%28k-2*3%2B2%2B%281-%28-1%29%5Ek%29%2F2%29%2F2%2B2*3-1-%281-%28-1%29%5Ek%29%283-1%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+0%2C+7%7D%5D) and $n=4$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B%28-1%29%5E%28k%2B1%29*abs%28k-2*4%2B2%2B%281-%28-1%29%5Ek%29%2F2%29%2F2%2B2*4-1-%281-%28-1%29%5Ek%29%284-1%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+0%2C+11%7D%5D).